# Apps are randomly opening up after unlocking my Redmi Note 4 through fingerprint sensor?

Tags: xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I am experiencing this for about 2-3 weeks.
When I unlock my phone a random app(which are on home screen, I think) opens up automatically.
The apps which I mainly noticed are WhatsApp and themes.

Is this a result of malware or anything else? How to fix?
I did a bit of research on it sites like [quora](https://www.quora.com/Every-time-I-unlock-my-Android-phone-it-opens-Google-Chrome-all-by-itself-and-thus-more-tabs-open-every-time-Is-this-a-virus), [android central](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-5/574323-apps-randomly-popping-open-when-i-unlock.html%3famp), etc.

But none of them seems to work for me.

Comment: How you have installed apps? From play store or downloaded apk. Check these steps, Goto Settings->Installed Applications->SystemLauncher. Clear its cache and data. Check whether it is solved or not.

Comment: I always install from play store only

Comment: I can't tell it is solved or not because it doesn't happen after every unlock instead happens at any random time.

Comment: Could you please tell how it is gonna fix by clearing cache and data?

Comment: By clearing cache and data of system launcher your home screen will reset to default. That means your present arrangement of apps and widgets are lost and reset to which you have seen on first boot.  If the issue is with launcher, then it may be get solved.

Comment: Sure. No apps get uninstalled. Only changes home screen arrangement.

Comment: One last thing, is it a known issue in Xiaomi phones?

Comment: No. I have used Xiaomi phone last three years, and  I haven't had this issue. Else you can try installing another launcher(Nova) from Play Store. Launcher is the Application that loads apps and defines user interface of device. Nova launcher(stock android like UI) is different from current MIUI arrangement.

Comment: @Rahul Gopi Unfortunately it doesn't resolved the issue:-(

Comment: Have you tried with Nova launcher?

Comment: I didn't tried Nova

Comment: If still happens the same after Nova, then try by reset, and again it still happens, then the issue is with touch screen.

Comment: Okay I will try my luck with launchers